# PHP file running with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file that automatically inserts and another one that updates my database, i need a script that will allow me to run these 2 file on background without me having to click any buttons.

Comment: you can use cron jobs.

Comment: `cron`, or any similar task scheduling system, can be used to automatically execute things in the background at scheduled intervals.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? Have User Data be inserted into your DB or do you collect data with it? How do you want those files to be activated?

Comment: the files allow to import data from one database to another without bothering to do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it with JS interval

```
setInterval(function(){ /* AJAX request */ }, 3000);
```

Since cronjob was mentioned for scheduled tasks, it has advantages over infinite loop like that, however questioner mentioned AJAX so this is AJAX solution to repeatable tasks, it of course will only run if client runs the application and is better solution for client based functionality like checking new messages, detecting user status updates or even chat, so simplified it will look like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/myTasks.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {/* Some data to send to server */},
            beforeSend: function () {
               /* Do some stuff before sending */
            },
            success: function (RecievedData) {
                /* Do some stuff after recieving */
            },
            error: function (RecievedData, textStatus) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(RecievedData));
                //console.log(textStatus);
            },
            complete: function (RecievedData) {
               /* Do some stuff regardless success or fail */
            }
        });
    };    
}, 1000);// one second interval
});
```

I'm using Jquery here just for the sake of example

Answer (score 0):

you must use the crontab ...
You can access (from linux) the file listing all your cron tasks with the command:

## crontab -l

To edit this file just do:

## crontab -e

For example, you can add something like this to this file:
0 2 * * * php -f /folder/file_insert.php